# Spring data JPA : Wrapper class on JPA entity and repository class

Tags: java, generics, spring-data-jpa

I have two JPA entities (Product,ProductCustomer) and its corresponding JPA repositories (ProductRepository,ProductCustomerRepository). My use case is to invoke findAll() method of both the repositories and write the resultset in an excel.

Instead of Autowiring each and every repository (repositories may grow in future) and invoking findAll method, i want to wrap the entity object and repository object with a generic object which will be used to invoke the findAll method of each and every repository.

For example:

```
public class GenericEntity {

}

@Entity
@Table(name="Product")
public class Product extends GenericEntity{
}
```

GenericRepository :

```
public interface GenericRepository<T extends GenericEntity> extends JpaRepository<T, Integer> {
}
```

ProductRepository:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends GenericRepository<Product>{
}
```

Execute method during start up:

```
    GenericRepository repo = (GenericRepository) context.getBean("productRepository");

List<GenericEntity> dataList = repo.findAll();
```

When i try to attempt this, JPA expects @Entity and @Id annotation on the wrapper (GenericEntity). Is there any way i can achieve this use case using Java generics?

Comment: Nope. Jpa reads the annotations at runtime, generics exist at compile time.

Comment: This setup appears to be very complex for any potential benefits. If you don't want to autowire a bunch of repos in a bunch of services, you could make a composite service that autowires all the repos and then just autowire the composite service across your entire application.

Comment: What's the advantage of getting the repository beans by name rather than by autowiring?

Comment: The idea is, i will scan a package with repositories and store it in a static list or map and this piece of code will be executed in static block. Then i will iterate the collection to invoke findAll() method of each repository, write every record in an excel and proceed with other repository.  GenericRepository repo = (GenericRepository) context.getBean("productRepository"); will be replaced as GenericRepository repo = (GenericRepository) context.getBean(repoListItr); I want to avoid writing findAll() invocation of each and every repository then writing the resultset to excel